# The functional $f : c_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ has a unique Hahn - Banach extension

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $c_0$ be the vector space of real valued sequence converging to $0$. Show that any bounded linear functional $f : c_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ has a unique Hahn-Banach extension $\hat{f} : \ell_{∞} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I know that $(c_0)^* = \ell_1$ and $(\ell_1)^*= \ell_∞$, and therefore $(c_0)^{**} = \ell_∞$.

I also know that $(c_0, \Vert \cdot \Vert _∞ )$ is Banach, but don't know if this is usable in this case, as it the norm is not specified.

EDIT:

I am not sure how to prove that this functional is unique.
I have learned that this statement is false if I am concerning "all linear functionals", so I am assuming it is meant to be "all bounded linear functionals" instead.

Comment: What is the problem with existence of the extenstion? You say you know Hahn Banach Theorem. What does the theorem say?

Comment: Do you mean linear functional or continuous linear functional? The result is false if you are considering all linear functionals.

Comment: Oh, right! So I only need to show that this functional is unique?

Comment: In my problem set it says "any linear functional", but in the book it says "any bounded linear functional". So I am assuming that it is the last one, since I am asked to prove the uniqueness.

Comment: +1. Now it looks like  a good question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniqueness of Hahn-Banach extensions for $c_0 \subseteq \ell^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190322/uniqueness-of-hahn-banach-extensions-for-c-0-subseteq-ell-infty)

Comment: The answer linked by Christian does not say it explicitly, but uniqueness is still wrong if you assume boundedness. It is only true if you're looking for extensions of the same norm.