# How to prove that the Hahn-Banach extension in this case is unique

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I am struck on a problem in my operator theory class so I am posting it here in the hope of getting some help.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $E\subseteq H$ be a closed subspace. Show that if $\phi \in E^{*}$ , then $\phi$ has a unique Hahn Banach extension $\psi \in H^{*}$.

As $H$ is a hilbert space and so a topological vector space which is locally convex so the Hahn-Banach theorem is valid. The theorem as given in my lectures is :  Let $X$ is a topological vector space which is locally convex over $\mathbb{K} \in $ {$\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C}$} . Let $E$ be a subspace of $X$ and $\phi^{'}: E\to \mathbb{K}$ be a subspace of $X$  and $\phi: E\to \mathbb{K}$ continuous linear form. Then there exists a continuous linear form $\phi|_{E} =\phi^{'} $.

Using the above theorem , it can be deduced that the extension exists.

Now let there exists 2 extension $\phi$  and $\psi$. Now, as a Hilbert space is a normed space. So, such extensions will satisfy the following ( by a corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem): $||\phi ||=||\phi^{'} || =||\psi||$.

> But I don't have any ideas on how to prove the equality.

Kindly help!

Comment: Hint: Do you know about the correspondence between a Hilbert space and its dual?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827816/uniqueness-of-hahn-banach-extension-for-convex-dual-spaces

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't  think it is covered in my class notes. Do you mind writing a statement?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190322/uniqueness-of-hahn-banach-extensions-for-c-0-subseteq-ell-infty

Comment: The continuous extension won't be unique unless you *impose* it has the same norm (think for instance of $\phi=0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in H$ there are unique $x_1,x_2$ such that $x=x_1+x_2$ with $x_1\in E$ and $x_2\in E^{\perp}$  (i.e. the inner product $(x_2,z)=0$ for every $z\in E).$ We have $x\in E\iff x=x_1.$ And $\|x\|^2=\|x_1\|^2+\|x_2\|^2$  for all $x.$

The case $\phi=0$ is trivial.

For $\phi\ne 0,$ suppose $0<r=\sup \{\frac {|\psi (y)|}{\|y\|}:0\ne y\in E^{\perp }\}.$ Then $$(1).....\|\psi\|\ge \sup \left\{\frac {|\phi (x)+s\cdot \psi (y)|}{\|x+sy\|}: x\in E\land y\in E^{\perp }\land \|x\|=\|y\|=1\land s>0\right\}\ge$$ $$(2)....\ge\sup \left\{\frac {|\phi (x)+s\cdot \psi (y)|}{1+s^2/2}: x\in E\land y\in E^{\perp }\land \|x\|=\|y\|=1\land s>0\right\}\ge$$ $$(3)....\ge\sup \left\{\frac{|\phi (x)|+s\cdot |\psi (y)|}{1+s^2/2}: x\in E\land y\in E^{\perp}\land \|x\|=\|y\|=1\land s>0\right\}=$$
$$(4).... =\|\phi\|+r\cdot\sup_{s>0}\frac {s}{1+s^2/2}>\|\phi\|,$$ contrary to $\|\psi\|=\|\phi\|.$

Therefore $\psi(y)=0$ for all $y\in E^{\perp}.$ So for all $x,$ with $x_1,x_2$ as in the 1st sentence above, we have $\psi(x)=\psi(x_1)+\psi (x_2)=\psi(x_1)=\phi(x_1).$

Explanation:(i). The denominator in $(1)$ satisfies $\|x+sy\|=(1+s^2)^{1/2}<1+s^2/2$....(ii). The transition from $(2)$ to $(3)$ is justified because in $(3)$ we are restricting the set of $x,y$ to  a smaller set, namely those for which $|\phi(x)+s\cdot\psi(y)|=|\phi(x)|+s\cdot|\psi(y)|.$ Also, to get from $(3$ to $(4)$, for every $x\in E, y\in E^{\perp}$ there are scalars $k, k'$ such that $|k|=|k'|=1$ and $|\phi(kx)+s\cdot\psi(k'y)|=|\phi(x)|+s\cdot|\psi(y)|.$

Comment: Uniqueness of $\psi$ does not hold for all Banach spaces. We must use some of the special properties of Hilbert space.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I am not able able to understand how you wrote equation (1) : $"(1).....\|\psi\|\ge \sup \left\{\frac {|\phi (x)+s\cdot \psi (y)|}{\|x+sy\|}: x\in E\land y\in E^{\perp }\land \|x\|=\|y\|=1\land s>0\right\}\geq"$ ie how you wrote the inequality. Can you please add an explanation for it?

Comment: Let $F=\{x+sy:x\in E\land y\in E^{\perp }\land \|x\|=\|y\|=1\land s>0\}.$ Then $0\not\in F\subset H$ so $\|\psi\|=\sup \{|\psi(u)|/\|u\|:0\ne  u\in H\}\ge$ $ \sup \{|\psi(u)|/\|u\|:  u\in F\}$, and this last expression is the RHS of $(1)$.

Comment: Intuitively the idea was that if $\phi\ne 0$ and $r>0,$ then if  $\phi(x)=\|\phi\|$ and $\psi(y)=r,$ with $x\in E, y\in E^{\perp}$, with $ \|x\|=\|y\|=1,$ then for sufficiently small $s>0$ we would have $|\psi(x+sy)|=$ $\|\phi\|+sr=$ $=\|\phi\|(1+\frac {sr}{\|\phi\|})>$ $\|\phi\|(1+s^2/2)>$ $\|\phi\|\cdot \|x+sy\|,$ implying $\|\psi\|>\|\phi\|.$